# Class String has not instance getter in flutter

Tags: flutter

I get an error of

```
Exception caught by gesture
Class 'String' has no instance getter 'status'
Receiver: 'Under PUI'
Tried calling: status
```

when I select my Radio Button. I get this radio button from firebase. Please see my codes below:

```
class HealthStatusList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HealthStatusState createState() => _HealthStatusState();
}

class _HealthStatusState extends State<HealthStatusList> {
  List<HealthStatus> healthStatusList = new List<HealthStatus>();

  HealthStatus selectedHealthStatus;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final healthStatuses = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);
    // print(healthStatuses.documents);

    for (var doc in healthStatuses.documents) {
      int pos = doc.data['position'];
      String sts = doc.data['status'];
      String stc = doc.data['statusCode'];
      HealthStatus hs =
          new HealthStatus(position: pos, status: sts, statusCode: stc);
      healthStatusList.add(hs);
      print(doc.data['position']);
    }

    setSelectedHealthStatus(HealthStatus hs) {
      setState(() {
        selectedHealthStatus = hs;
      });
    }

    List<Widget> createRadioListeners() {
      List<Widget> widgets = [];
      for (HealthStatus hs in healthStatusList) {
        widgets.add(RadioListTile(
          value: hs.status,
          groupValue: selectedHealthStatus,
          title: Text(hs.status),
          onChanged: (currentStatus) {
            print("Current Status ${currentStatus.status}");
            setSelectedHealthStatus(currentStatus);
          },
          selected: selectedHealthStatus == hs,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        ));
      }
      return widgets;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text('How are you feeling?'),
          ),
          Column(
            children: createRadioListeners(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the HealthStatus class

```
class HealthStatus {
  final int position;
  final String status;
  final String statusCode;

  HealthStatus({this.position, this.status, this.statusCode});

  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return status;
  }
}
```

When I select the radio button, I should get the string 'status' string.

Also, when I click the radio button, I do not see the dot on the radio button I have selected. Could you please point to me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you check `print("Current Status ${currentStatus}");`.What is the output?

Comment: That is the output Sir.
Exception caught by gesture
    Class 'String' has no instance getter 'status' 
    Receiver: 'Under PUI'
    Tried calling: status 
When the print is invoked, that what comes out. The string of the selected radio button actually comes out but it is in the part of 
Receiver: 'Under PUI'

Comment: Because `Under PUI` is a String. What output you expected it will print?

Comment: I should get the '"Current Status Under PUI" or "Current Status <whatever the selected item>". Please see my edit.

Comment: I should get the '"Current Status Under PUI" or "Current Status <whatever the selected item>". Please see my edit.

Comment: I think I get the part of the error: I was able to fix it by changing to this code. `print("Current Status: " + currentStatus.toString());` . My concern now is, The radio button does not indicate that it was selected. Meaning, the UI does not show or the selected radio button does not change in appearance to indicate that it was selected.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
selected: selectedHealthStatus == hs,
```

should be

```
selected: selectedHealthStatus == hs.status,
```